# How to call other method with same name form other package in following context

Tags: java, interface, package

How can I call a method of `class B` from `Package.one` when the same method is available in `class B` in `Package.two`? `main()` is in `class RunAB` in `Package.two`.

```
Package
 |-----one
 |      |---A.java (interface)
 |      |---B.java (implements A)
 |-----two
        |---B.java (implements A)
        |---RunAB.java
```

//Package.one dir

```
package Package.one;

public interface A {
    int area(); 
}
```

.

```
package Package.one;

public class B implements A {
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public int area() {
        System.out.println("i am form one");
        return width*height;
    }

    public B(int a, int b) {
        width = a;
        height = b; 
    }
}
```

//Package.two dir

```
package Package.two;

import Package.one.*;

class B implements A {
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public int area() {
        System.out.println("i am form two");
        return width*height;
    }

    public B(int a, int b) {
        width = a;
        height = b; 
    }
}
```

.

```
package Package.two;
import Package.one.*;


class RunAB {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B(10,12);
        System.out.println("area is " + b.area());

    }
}
```

///output ;

```
i am form two
area is 120
```

How does Java know that it needs to call the method from package two and not from Package one? Is there any role of `interface A` in this calling process (decision)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fully qualified name:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Package.one.B b = new Package.one.B(10,12);
    System.out.println("area is " + b.area());
}
```

Adressing your second question, run this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    pack.one.B bFromOne = new pack.one.B(10,12);
    System.out.println(bFromOne.area());
    pack.two.B bFromTwo = new pack.two.B(10,12);
    System.out.println(bFromTwo.area());
}
```

You only have to use the fully qualified name, if that class is hidden through another import.

---

In future, please respect the Java naming conventions and have your packages start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I really don't know about naming conventions for packages. but i now about class, and method. Is they correct.  thanks

Comment: @netsmertia: Yes, all your names follow the naming conventions. The uppercase `P` at the beginning of your package name `Package` is the only mistake.

Comment: thanks for it. I love to follow conventions, but new to java. i am form php background. is there any answer for how it know(second qestion)

Comment: @netsmertia: The method associated with the object is called. Here, you instantiate `B` from the package `Package.one` is instantiated, so it's method is called. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your input. and any suggestion for good book with objective type questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since `package.one.B` is *not* static we need to get an instance of `package.one.B` first. We use the fully-qualified classname:

```
package.one.B myBOne=new package.one.B(16,24);
System.out.println("area is " + myBOne.area());
```

If we were calling a static method, it would be the fully qualified name followed by the method name.

If `package.one.B` had a static method `staticFoo(` we'd use `package.one.B.staticfoo()`

When these classes implememt the interface they do so independently of one another and do not need to be aware that the other is also implementing it.

Comment: Ok, i tried it with `B b = new package.one.B(16,24)` but don't know about left hand side `package.one.B b` thanks

Comment: @netsmertia The thing you tried with shouldn't work since package.one.B doesn't extend package.two.B.

Comment: so without fully qualified class name `B b`. java consider it in current package `package.two` and in right hand side i assign a object with `package.one` right.

Comment: @netsmertia No. You use the same type on both sides. And remove your input statement,

Comment: i think you get me wrong, In my first comment i give what mistake i made when i try this (fully qualified class). and in second i give cause of that problem. and ask you, Is  reason for that error is right.

Comment: @netsmertia I can't understand your comment at all. The point is that you should remove the import and use what I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import it. When creating objects from a different package use the following format in your code

```
Package.one.A a = new Package.one.A();
```